# Why encryption functionalities are not showing up in Disks utility

Tags: encryption

I have been trying to encrypt an external hd but I do not get the encryption  option in Disks when I start the formatting process.

I have installed cryptsetup but I still does not work

Comment: Have you tried with other disks?

Comment: What do you mean? Disks is a software

Comment: I mean hds, usbs

Comment: no I have not. Anyway I cannot find the hds package anywhere in synaptic

Comment: i am not familiar with the gui. have you tried it via terminal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a LUKS encrypted drive or partition from the **Disks** (`gnome-disk-utility`) application:

1. In the **Disks** application, from the side bar, select the physical disk on which you want to create an encrypted partition.
2. Select the "**Free Space**" partition you want to encrypt.

   *If you do not have any empty partitions, you must make room for one by deleting an existing partition.  **WARNING!**: This will effectively delete all data on the partition.*
3. Click the `+` icon to **Create partition in unallocated space**.
4. Adjust partition size (Default: max) and click ***NEXT***
5. Make up a volume name.  Select: **Internal disk for use with Linux systems only (Ext4)** and check **Password protect volume (LUKS)** then click ***CREATE***.
6. Set your password and click ***CREATE***.

You now should have a LUKS encrypted partition.

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks